# Read JS variables in php

Tags: javascript, variables

I am using the following to get js variables to a php file. The alert seems to be given the correct data.

```
   var str =  $("form").serialize();
        alert('test '+str);
        //console.log('test '+str);
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "saveData.php",
            data: str,
```

and i the php file i tried

`echo 'Test name: '.$_REQUEST["name"];//only got the test name`

also
`print_r($_REQUEST);`

and even tried

```
$values = array();
parse_str($_REQUEST['str'], $values);
print_r($values);
```

But without succes, any tips or info?

Comment: What is the value of `str`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data` should be done as follows:

```
   var str =  $("form").serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "saveData.php",
            data: {name: str},
```

This way you should be able to obtain the value in PHP via `$_REQUEST["name"]`